# Schema is not a constructor When defining model in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am  creating  application for   book  store

```
var  _mongoose  =  require("mongoose");
var  Schema =  _mongoose.Schema();
var  books  =  new Schema ({
 title : { type : String},
author : { type : String},
genre  : { type: String},
read  : { type : Boolean, default  : false}
});

module.exports = _mongoose.Model('Books',books);
```

This Code is giving  error :

```
var  books  =  new Schema ({
           ^

TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
```

As  i am new to  node  js please suggest how to proceed.

Version  on  mongoose  and express

```
{
"express": "^4.15.4",

"mongoose": "^4.11.12"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `var  Schema =  _mongoose.Schema;`

Comment: Now its  giving me error  when  using  _mongoose.Schema--  this.$__.strictMode = schema.options && schema.options.strict;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Comment: var books = new Books({title: 'smth', author: 'smth', genre: 'smth', read: true});

Comment: @EmirMaljanovic  :-  its  giving me compile time error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working example:

```
var _mongoose  = require("mongoose");
var Books  = new _mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    author: { type: String },
    genre: { type: String },
    read: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

module.exports = _mongoose.model('Books', Books);
```

you are calling Schema twice and mongoose.model is all lowercase. Check the doc http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

Comment: _mongoose.model('Books',books);  this works  ... Thanks